# how to get all values from a array without getting mix with sql query?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, codeigniter

I have a array call newArray();

```
$values = array_count_values($books);

arsort($values);

$newArray = array_keys($values);
```

it have data like below

```
Array ( [0] => 37 [1] => 31 [2] => 29 [3] => 28 [4] => 20 [5] => 26 [6] => 34 [7] => 30 [8] => 25 )
```

how can i get first 5 index in that array and how to write query for those remain values

**as example**

[0]=>37 from this

get books from books table that id equals to 37 something like that

please help me with this
anything will be helpful

**EDIT**

array have values like this

```
Array ( [0] => 37 [1] => 31 [2] => 29 [3] => 28 [4] => 20 [5] => 26 [6] => 34 [7] => 30 [8] => 25 )
```

function like below

```
if(!empty($books)) {    

            $values = array_count_values($books);

            arsort($values);

            $newArray = array_keys($values);

            $views_books_array = array_slice($newArray, 0, 5);

            $result = $this->db->where_in('book_id',$views_books_array)->get('books');

            print_r($result);
            return $result->result_array();
}
```

> $result not getting what i need what did i do wrong?

Comment: Do you mean SQL query? SQL isn't really meant ta handle arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) function:

```
// it will get 5 values from $books, starting from 0 offset (first position)
$values = array_count_values(array_slice($books, 0, 5));
```

Comment: how can i get only values

Comment: so i can use values to retrieve from database

Comment: @HemalHerath you can access values directly from an array. Your question is bit unclear. Expected output as per your given sample dataset would be helpful

Comment: I have ediited my question can you look it up sir

Comment: @HemalHerath nominated for reopening